# tip calc equation working on first output but returning NaN on second output with number()

Tags: javascript

see codepen here

https://codepen.io/jimandrews89/pen/zbpRdm

```
document.getElementById('container').onchange = function() {
  var bill = Number(document.getElementById('billTotal').value);
  var tipPercent = Number(document.querySelector('input[name = "tip"]:checked').value);
  var split = Number(document.getElementsByName('number-of-people').value);
  var tipTotal = bill * tipPercent;
  var finalTotal = (bill + tipTotal) / split;

document.getElementById('newTipTotal').innerHTML = tipTotal;
document.getElementById('newTotalWithTip').innerHTML = finalTotal;}
```

The last output should calculate the bill + tip divided among the number of people paying. The first output isn't broken so I don't know why the second out is. At first, I thought of using parseInt() rather than Number() to convert the string to a number but that made the first output NaN aswell.

Comment: Log all of your values before you do the math operations. I'm willing to bet they're not all numbers. Since the final output is the one that uses `split` - my money is on `split` being an empty string or null

Comment: `document.getElementsByName` -> `document.getElementById`

Comment: I agree with @tymeJV, a great practice is to slowly add things and log as you go. One tip for ensuring you are working with numbers is to use `console.log(typeof variable);`. This will log the type of data you are working with. `console.log(typeof "1"); // logs string`, whereas `console.log(typeof 1); // logs number`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO Jim!

While the previous responses are correct, having you calculate everything using the `container onchange` function will result in errors whenever some of the data is missing. For example, when you first change the `billTotal` (and haven't changed anything else yet), you will get an uncaught type error (`TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at HTMLDivElement.document.getElementById.onchange`) where the page is looking for the non-existent values of your tip percent and how-many-people.

Without changing your html, here is an alternate solution. This has `onchange` listeners for each input of data, updating and saving the values as you gather them. Once all the data exists, it then calculates the total.

A few new things I threw in here are [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), these methods are great for converting strings of numbers `"1"` into actual numbers `1`.

```
let billInput = document.getElementById('billTotal');
let tipPercentInput = document.getElementById('tipPercent');
let splitInput = document.getElementById('number-of-people');

let billValue = false;
let tipPercentValue = false;
let splitValue = false;

billInput.onchange = function() {
    billValue = parseInt(billInput.value);
    calculateTip();
}

tipPercentInput.onchange = function() {
    tipPercentValue = parseFloat(document.querySelector('input[name = "tip"]:checked').value);
    calculateTip();
}

splitInput.onchange = function() {
    splitValue = parseInt(splitInput.value);
    calculateTip();
}

function calculateTip() {
    if (billValue && tipPercentValue && splitValue) {
        let tipTotal = billValue * tipPercentValue;
        let finalTotal = (billValue + tipTotal) / splitValue;

        document.getElementById('newTipTotal').innerHTML = tipTotal;
        document.getElementById('newTotalWithTip').innerHTML = finalTotal;
    }
}
```

One way to take your code further, if you're looking at [accepting only numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number) in your form.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for this. So just to clarify... you make all three initial variables false, then the calculateTip() function is added after every input change to immediately check if all 3 initial variables are true before triggering? So if partial data is input, it won't trigger too soon? Only after all three variables have been altered with a user input, correct?

Comment: That is correct. Every time an `onchage` method is fired, it will assign the respective value to its variable, then it will check the `calculate` tip function, and if all variables have a value other than `false`, it will calculate the tip.

In this case, writing `if (billValue) {}` is the same as `if (billValue !== false) {}`

Comment: Cool. Makes sense since someone could enter data in a different order. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have `document.getElementsByName` instead of `document.getElementById`, thats why your split value is Nan. I have put the corrected code below. Tested code on link provided above.

```
document.getElementById('container').onchange = function() {
  var bill = Number(document.getElementById('billTotal').value);
  var tipPercent = Number(document.querySelector('input[name = "tip"]:checked').value);
  var split = Number(document.getElementById('number-of-people').value);
  var tipTotal = bill * tipPercent;
  var finalTotal = (bill + tipTotal) / split;

document.getElementById('newTipTotal').innerHTML = tipTotal;
document.getElementById('newTotalWithTip').innerHTML = finalTotal;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not added the attribute 'name' in input element for number of person.

You can use:

```
var split = Number(document.getElementById('number-of-people').value);
```